# aibo Web API にてaiboをジャイアント・パンダ、或いは豚の行動にすることが可能でしょうか？

Tags: aibo-developer

例えば、ジャイアント・パンダ或いは豚の動作をさせて、それらの鳴き声も出したいです。

aibo Web APIだけを用いて実現できない場合、ROSプログラミングにて実現可能でしょうか？　この場合、 aiboの各センサー・アクチュエータなどのROSモジュールを公開可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

現在公開されている API では、ジャイアント・パンダや豚の行動そのものを実行させるものはありません。
また、aibo の各アクチュエーターを自由に動かしたり、音声を追加したりする API はご提供していません。
ROS プログラミングの開発環境もご提供していません。

---

aibo Web API で実行可能なことについては、以下のドキュメントでご確認ください。

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs

> aibo Web API とは、 インターネットを介して aibo にさまざまなことを行わせることができる Web API です。

特に動作系については Action API の項目をご確認ください。

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#action-api

> Action API について。 動作系の API です。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: ご提示の資料を読みますと、Web APIは「基本的に御社の専用サーバを経由して、
犬限定的な動作をさせたり、その情報を取得したり」することが可能ですが、
その鳴き声などが変えられませんね。
迅速なご解答誠にありがとうございます！